# JMeter prints summary view on the command line for one script but not another

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 JMeter scripts which I am running from the command line. In the first script, I can see the summary view on the console while the test is running. That is:

```
summary + 3234  in 00:00:30...
summary = 34872 in 00:31:30...
```

In the other script, none of the summary data is printed, although the script will run correctly and save the data to the output file.

I see the same behavior for these script whether I run them from a Windows command line or from Linux. What is the trick to enable the summary output for my second script?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. Your "other" script runs less than 30 seconds and by default Summariser "ticks" every 30 seconds. If this is the case you can amend `summariser.interval` property so it would occur more frequently
2. You have [Transaction Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) everywhere in your "other" script and by default Summariser doesn't report the sample results originating from the Transaction Controllers. If this is the case - set `summariser.ignore_transaction_controller_sample_result` property to `false`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Summariser - Generate Summary Results - configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#summariser)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing similar behavior. The result summary is not printed when I use conf path parameter to run the script. Whereas it is shown when I remove the -p parameter

jmeter -n -t fullpathtojmx -p fullpathtopropertiesfile -l fullpathtojtlfile